# How to fit multiple rotating rectangle inside the canvas (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

as mentioned I am trying to fit a whole circle of rectangle inside a canvas, but as seen, I can only show a fourth of the circle. I made a basic html document with a canvas element. Relative to the size of the canvas element I made a single rectangel and centered it in the middle of the canvas. With that, I tried to make a for loop which should rotate the rectangle while making a full circle. But it didn't work.

```css
body{
    background-color: #000000;
}

canvas {
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border:1px solid
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="canvas.css">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="900" ></canvas>
        
        <script>
        // Get id from canvas element
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        
        // Change size of rectangle
        var recWidth = 40
        var recHeight = 40
        
        // Position rectangle in the middle of the canvas    
        var xPos = (document.getElementById("myCanvas").width/2) - (recWidth/2);   
        var yPos = (document.getElementById("myCanvas").height/2) - (recHeight/2);
        

        // Convert degree to radian
        const degToRad = (degrees) => {
            return degrees / 180 * Math.PI;
        }    
        
        // Number of rectangles
        const num = 36;

        for (let i = 0; i<num; i++){
            const slice = degToRad (360 / num);
            const angle = slice * i; 

        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.save();
        context.rotate (angle);            
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(xPos,yPos,recWidth,recHeight);
        context.fill();
        context.restore();
        }

        </script> 
        
        </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm not violating SO protocols by creating a separate answer,
but I have done so to avoid some clutter with the new code.

Here is a cleaned up version of your code.
Explanation:
Move the center of rotation to the center of the canvas:
context.translate(width/2, height/2)
Then specify the radius for drawing as a quarter of canvas dimension.
rad = xPos/2
Do the rotation one slice at a time, leaving it in place (no save/restore).
(incorrect statement removed)

```
<script>
// Get id from canvas element
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.font = "14pt Arial";
context.fillStyle = "green";

// Change size of rectangle
var recWidth = 30
var recHeight = 30

// Position rectangle in the middle of the canvas    


var canvW = document.getElementById("myCanvas").width;
var canvH = document.getElementById("myCanvas").height;
var xPos = canvW/2;
var yPos = canvH/2;
var rad = xPos/2;  // radius = 1/4 of canvas dimensions
context.translate(xPos,yPos);  // rotate around the center

// Convert degree to radian
const degToRad = (degrees) => {
    return degrees / 180 * Math.PI;
}    

// Number of rectangles
const num = 36;
const slice = degToRad (360 / num);
const angle = slice; 

// animates the drawing to help see what is going on
// by introducing 1/2 second delay between individual draws
function draw1Rect(i)
    {
        i++;
        if (i < num) setTimeout("draw1Rect("+i+")", 500);
        context.rotate (angle);            
        context.fillRect(rad,rad,recWidth,recHeight);
        context.fillText(i, rad-30, rad-30);
    }
    draw1Rect(0);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me, understanding what was the issue and the animation is a neat trick for playing around with it. I truly appreciate it, going out of your way and explaining it to me, even though I already checked the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that most of your squares are being drawn outside the boundaries of the canvas.

It appears the canvas rotates around (0, 0) rather than around the center.

Outside the loop:

```
// Use a different center and a smaller radius
var xPos = (document.getElementById("myCanvas").width/4) - (recWidth/4);   
var yPos = (document.getElementById("myCanvas").height/4) - (recHeight/4);
// Move the center 
context.translate(xPos * 2, yPos * 9/4);
context.font = "14pt Arial";
```

Inside the loop:

```
context.fill(); // existing line of code
context.fillText(i, xPos-30, yPos-30); // added
context.restore(); // existing
```

Also: instead of context.beginPath(), context.rect() and context.fill() you can use context.fillRect().

Comment: Thank you. For now it seems to have worked. But I was wondering if it is possible to make the "moved center" to be exactly as the center of the canvas? The numbers you have used seemed to be a little off in my html document. Instead of 9/4, I used 2.1, which close and it seems to work, visually speaking. I have planned to add more code such as a random number generator but I am worried, I have to change the center point everytime I refresh the html page. I have generally have a hard time with JS since I am self-taught.